# Specific debugging tips/tools to track down memory corruption?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory

I'm writing a simple video encoder that compresses YUV420p video. I noticed that the resulting file always looks slightly different when I regenerate it from the same input file with the same compression settings. No big changes, it's usually just a few bits that suffer from a "cosmic ray bit flip" effect.

At no point in my program I use randomized values, so the resulting output should always be the same. I suspect that my program performs reads/writes outside its allocated memory, which would explain the randomness of the data.

Aside from regular debugging practices, are there special tools/tricks to help me detect the cause of these shenanigans?

Comment: a) use idiomatic C++ (no pointers or `new`), b) run the program though a memory debugger such as `valgrind`.

Comment: Place sentinal values at the beginning and end of your buffers.  Check them when done.

Comment: Does IBM still make Purify?  That was an awesome tool when I was last doing C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If on Windows OS, you can try [AppVerifier](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20028)

Comment: I'll second this one - Application Verifier has helped us track down memory corruption quite well in the past.

Answer (score 0):

- use debug variants of your containers
- use your containers' interfaces rather than raw memory
- MallocDebug
- MallocLogging
- valgrind
- MallocScribble
- in some cases, you can perform an operation twice with what you should expect to be equal results - verify the results match (note that you should not compare memory directly, but use the interfaces).
- if you know the algorithms employed well enough, you could provide an input which you can analyze the output for errors (e.g. "if the input is a black frame, the output should also be a black frame").

*not sure which platform you are developing on. the tools mentioned are for 'nixes and OS X (also a 'nix but...)*

Answer (score 0):

You can make one output record then make another one. And during the process of compressing in each output bit of the former you can compare with the same bit of the latter. I don't know the compressor. But if you have several stages of compressing you can make several records of different stages for the first resulted record. When compressing the second resulted record you need to compare bits at each stage to the bits of a correspondent records of the first output. As a result you can find a certain place which corrupts bits.